# Why UPDATE query not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my code

```
UPDATE project SET name = 'New Name' AND platform = 'iOS' WHERE id = 2
```

When I process it via phpMyAdmin, it is changing the name to `0`. When I rerun the query, it says 0 rows affected. When I change back the name to something else and rerun the query, it says 1 row affected, but changing the name back to 0 and nothing else.

What am I doing wrong?

I have the table with proper structure and have a record with `id=2`

Comment: `name = 'New Name' AND platform = 'iOS'` should be `name = 'New Name' , platform = 'iOS'`

Comment: UPDATE project SET name = 'New Name'  WHERE id = 2 AND platform = 'iOS'; try this

Comment: Thanks all, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` syntax is wrong. It should be this:

```
UPDATE project SET name = 'New Name', platform = 'iOS' WHERE id = 2
```

MySQL is changing `name` to `0` because it is confused about what you mean by `AND`. It's possible MySQL is interpreting that statement to be a logical expression, which gets converted into a `1` for `TRUE` or a `0` for `FALSE` (in this case, the latter).

Think of your original query like this, with parentheses used to illustrate [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html):

```
UPDATE project SET name = ('New Name' AND (platform = 'iOS')) WHERE id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your explication. :) I am marking this as accepted because you explained what happened and why it set 0. :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove `AND` and use `,` instead

```
UPDATE project SET name = 'New Name', platform = 'iOS' WHERE id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE project SET name = 'New Name', platform = 'iOS' WHERE id = 2`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, correct syntax is

```
 UPDATE project SET name = 'New Name', platform = 'iOS' WHERE id = 2;
```

Or

```
 UPDATE project SET name = 'New Name' WHERE id = 2 AND platform = 'IOS';
```